# Need jQuery and basic architecture for a Google Chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I need a jquery extension to automatically change links from google searches from this:

`<a ... href='google.com/?q=some_pingback...'... data-href='the actual url'>`

to this:

`<a href='the actual url' ...>`

Google's main search page rarely uses this old pingback method but the results from google news still commonly have them. they prevent official filter extensions like Google Search Filter from functioning properly.

Can someone provide me with a framework to build this, and the basic jquery I'd need to get it to work?

edit: looking though extensions already out there, I found I could load jQuery and custom scripts very easily with extensions like Control Freak. The final code I use is:

```
jQ=window.jQuery;
setTimeout(function(){
    jQ('h3.r > a:first-child, span.tl > a:first-child').each(function(i,m){ 
        new_element='<a href="' + jQ(m).prop("href") + '">' + jQ(m).html() + '</a>';
    jQ(m).replaceWith(new_element);
    });
},667);
```

This is because, even though the respondent was correct for non-google search results (like in a [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/22EK5/)), google hoses the `<a>` links it makes so you can't do handle it like normal. To jQuery, such links appear to not have data-href tags, and appear to have the url from the data-href already set in the typicla href field. So you have to replace the entire link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `attr` or `prop` call can solve the problem:

```
$('a').prop('href', function() {
   return this.dataset.href;
   //  return $(this).data('href');
});
```

It basically iterates through the selected elements and sets the `href` property of them using their `data-href` attribute.

Comment: Which you need to do from a content script. See the official samples.

Comment: hey please vote my question up, won't you? It was a legitimate question and you've answered it.